# Tables appear in sqlite_master. Some work, some don't

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a spinner which populates from

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

I use that spinner to feed other database actions. Some of my tables can be used, others fail with the following exceptions, depending on the attempted action:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main.labs: , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO methods(name) VALUES(?);

11-16 06:32:01.927: E/Database(25403): Failure 1 (no such table: main.labs) on 0x1d6e48 when preparing 'DROP TABLE equipment_types'.
11-16 06:32:01.927: E/AssistantData(25403): drop table failed with exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: main.labs: DROP TABLE equipment_types

I've looked for a pattern of success/failure correlating with various characteristics of the tables, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Here is a create statement for a table which is working:

```
db.execSQL("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oel_sources 
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
name TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (name))");
```

One which is not working:

```
db.execSQL("
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS methods 
(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
 name TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (name))");
```

Each of these tables has one other table with a foreign key point to _id.

I have deleted the database with

```
context.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME));
```

I've also deleted it via application manager, uninstalled fully, and tried again. The working vs not working seems to be consistent across delete/recreates.

And, finally, I'm totally at a loss. Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Comment: `no such table: main.labs` during a `DROP TABLE equipment_types` sounds like an issue with your foreign ids. How do those two tables interact with each other?

Comment: @zapl You're correct! I'll submit a detailed answer, or you can take it if you like.

Comment: I have no idea how you solved your problem. So I guess it's better if you post an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After further review today, I found that all the tables not working were referenced by foreign keys from a single table. That table also referenced a non-existent table named "labs", as the error message was trying to tell me. I forgot I had even intended to create that table, so the name "labs" didn't light any bulbs. It was so late...

Lesson learned: you can create the db with a table holding a foreign key reference to a non-existent table. You can even complete operations on the table with the invalid reference. However, performing actions on other parent tables of the table with the invalid reference is what finally caused the error.

Seems strange, as I would have expected the parent tables to just sit there passively until some data in added to them and then the child table actually points to them, but I imagine there is a reason for this beyond my understanding.

Comment: It could be "*DROP TABLE command performs an implicit DELETE FROM <tbl>[...] an implicit DELETE FROM <tbl> does cause any configured foreign key actions to take place*" see [DROP TABLE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html)